# Count row number from a mysql table subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I have a table `department_courses` with following structure :

```
id   department_id   name  
--   -------------  -----
1    11             Abcd
2    11             Bghg
3    11             Lopps
4    13             Abvgf
```

So from this table I need to count the position of the subquery. I mean to say , The position of the `name` `Lopps` for `department_id` is 3 . How to get this in mysql query?

Comment: Please mention the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to do this for one row, then a single query is simpler:

```
select count(*)
from department_courses dc
where dc.id <= (select dc2.id
                from department_courses dc2
                where dc2.name = 'Lopps'
               );
```

If you want to assign a row number to all rows, then variables are probably a better method.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select row_num
from (
    select t.*, @r := @r + 1 row_num
    from department_courses t,
    (select @r := 0) r
) x
where x.name = 'Lopps'
x.department_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a row_number() feature you can utitilize:

```
SELECT id, 
       department_id, 
       name,
       row_number() over (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY department_id, name) as index
FROM department_courses
```